# changing DetailsViewMode on Page_Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, boundfield

I have a simple DetailsView control connected to a data source consisting of two T-SQL queries (which work fine). However, when I try to change the mode (depending on the id in the URL) to "Edit" on Page_Load event nothing shows while "Insert" works fine. Everything seems properly data-bound.

Also, how do I access the BoundField value (the text itself) from code-behind (FindControl always returns null for some reason)? I want to have a default value there when the page loads.

Markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="register" runat="server">
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DV" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            Height="100px" Width="170px" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="RegisterUser"
            OnItemCommand="Button_click"
            OnItemInserted="Insert_click" OnItemUpdated="Edit_click">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Name" 
                    SortExpression="username" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Text='<%# Bind("userPassword") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="userEmail" HeaderText="Email" 
                    SortExpression="userEmail" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" ShowEditButton="True"  />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:usersConnectionString %>" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO korisnik(username, userPassword, userEmail) VALUES (@username, @userPassword, @userEmail)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE korisnik SET userPassword = @userPassword, userEmail = @userEmail WHERE (username = @username)">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="userPassword" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="userEmail" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="userPassword" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="userEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Label ID="Message_label" ForeColor="red" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="[messageLabel]"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        // EDIT mode
        if (id == "Change_data_button")
        {
            DV.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit;
            //DV.DataSource = RegisterUser;
            //DV.DataBind();
            DV.Fields[0].Visible = false; // preventing the value from being changed (one cannot change a username)

            /* found this snippet somewhere but FindControl returns null */
            TextBox user;
            user = (TextBox)DV.FindControl("username");
            user.Text = Session["LoggedUser"].ToString();
        }
        // INSERT mode
        else if (id == "Register_button")
        {
            DV.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see any setting for `SelectCommand` in **SqlDataSource** control named `RegisterUser`, I don't think that you will have data in DetailsView to edit in EditMode.

So you have to set SelectCommand (also SelectParameters if have them) such as the following sample

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:usersConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM korisnik WHERE username = @username"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO korisnik(username, userPassword, userEmail) VALUES (@username, @userPassword, @userEmail)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE korisnik SET userPassword = @userPassword, userEmail = @userEmail WHERE (username = @username)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="userPassword" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="userEmail" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="userPassword" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="userEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Secound, in Page_Load handler, this line `user = (TextBox)DV.FindControl("username");` should always be null, because you don't have a control names "username", you have only DataField named "username".

If you want to hide username field in edit mode, you have to set username field as Key of DetailView (`DataKeyNames` setting). But I suggest that you could set username to be read-only instead of hiding it (set `ReadOnly="true"` in **BoundField**). Final, try to get their values in ItemUpdating event handler (`OnItemUpdating` setting)

Here is the sample as my suggestion:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DV" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    Height="100px" Width="170px" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="RegisterUser"
    OnItemCommand="Button_click"
    OnItemInserted="Insert_click" OnItemUpdated="Edit_click"
    OnItemUpdating="DV_ItemUpdating" 
    DataKeyNames="username">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Name" 
            SortExpression="username" 
            ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Text='<%# Bind("userPassword") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userEmail" HeaderText="Email" 
            SortExpression="userEmail" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" ShowEditButton="True"  />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Code-behide:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        // EDIT mode
        if (id == "Change_data_button")
        {
            DV.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit;
        }
        // INSERT mode
        else if (id == "Register_button")
        {
            DV.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
        }
    }
}
protected void DV_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string username = e.Keys["username"].ToString();

    TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)DV.FindControl("Password");
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    string email = e.NewValues["userEmail"].ToString();

    RegisterUser.UpdateParameters["userPassword"].DefaultValue = password;
    RegisterUser.UpdateParameters["userEmail"].DefaultValue = email;
    RegisterUser.UpdateParameters["username"].DefaultValue = username;

    RegisterUser.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: [**`DetailsView.ChangeMode()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.changemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to programmatically switch the `DetailsView` control between edit, insert, and read-only mode.

```
if (id == "Change_data_button")
        {
            DV.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
            //DV.DataSource = RegisterUser;
            //DV.DataBind();
         ...
         ...
        }
```

Also,  access the Bound Fields value as::

```
string _userName = DV.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
```